# Task Manager and its relevance to Java processes

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, concurrency, taskmanager

Under the performance tab in the Windows Task Manager, I see it displays information related to concurrency. Now my question is, where is displays the amount of processes is that how many application processes are running? And where is displays the amount of threads, is that the amount of process (application) threads are running? The reason I am asking this question is because I don't want to have its actual meaning mixed up with what I'd think. Thanks in advance! :)

Picture: http://www.upload.ee/image/4279214/question.png (I can't add pictures as I don't have 10+ reputation)

Would this:

```
public class ThreadAmountTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                while(true) {}
            }.start();
    }

}
```

Make the thread number rise?

EDIT: Also, where it says "handles", what does that mean?

Comment: The easiest way to find out is... try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the answer is yes, but it may depend on the JVM you're using and the settings you provide.

In early versions of Java (1.1), so called ["green threads"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120384/why-not-green-threads) were used which were managed by the JVM. On more recent virtual machines, native threads are used, where each thread in the JVM corresponds to an actual operating system thread. But there may be options on some virtual machines to switch to "green threads". (I'm not aware of any JVM implementation that still uses green threads, though.)

With recent versions of the 64-bit Oracle HotSpot Server JVM on Windows 7, I ran a test similar to yours and saw that the number of threads did go up in the Windows Task Manager. You would probably see similar results.

The "handles" are [object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725486(v=vs.85).aspx) [handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724485(v=vs.85).aspx), which correspond to various system resources (files, threads, windows, etc.) that the operating system has allocated to running programs.

Comment: Hey David, sorry for the late reply but thanks for your answer!

Comment: Done, I'd also increase your reputation however I apparently need 15+ to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use visualvm which will give the exact data what you are looking for & you can also use jconsole, both are rich GUI for monitoring java process

Comment: See java documentation for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer starlord, what about "Java Mission Control"?